# Multiple file renaming error

Tags: php, file-rename

Am using `PHP` to rename multiple files, It works perfect but i need to save file only the random number as file name

But in my case i get random number + file name

When i remove the file name the images saved without `extension`

i need to save file with renamed name only, i need to remove file name and save with random number i use this method for generating random number `$newname = md5(rand() * time());`

here is rename part`move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $newname . $file_name);` When i remove `$file_name` the output file is saved without extension

**Here my Code**

```
<?php

$db_username = 'sanoj';
$db_password = '123456';
if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $finfo = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
        $extension = '';
        if (!empty($finfo[PATHINFO_EXTENSION])) {
            $extension = "." . $finfo[PATHINFO_EXTENSION];
        }
        $file_name = md5(rand() * time()) . "." . $extension;

        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $desired_dir = "user_data/";
        if (empty($errors) == true) {
            if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if (is_dir("$desired_dir/" . $file_name) == false) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" .  $file_name);
            } else {                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir = "$desired_dir/" ;
                rename($file_tmp, $new_dir);
            }
        } else {
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }
```

**Important** above code works on multiple image upload

Comment: Or can i rename file after file stored in server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the extension of the file, check, is there extension, if yes, then attach to it, create the random number, and merge the number with extension :

```
$finfo = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
$extension = '';
if (!empty($finfo[PATHINFO_EXTENSION])) {
    $extension = "." . $finfo[PATHINFO_EXTENSION];
}
$file_name = md5(rand() * time()) . "." . $extension;
```

Comment: can you please help me where do i need to change

Comment: replace the line of `$file_name = ...` with my code.

Comment: i have update my code in question and i can see only file save that doesn't have EXTENSION

Answer (score 0):

```
$extension = end(explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name'])); 
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $newname.".".$extension);
```

please try this instead of

```
 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $newname . $file_name);
```

Comment: i think you have to read above question again when i remove  `$file_name` the output image is saved without extension

Comment: i have [$key] this function makes multiple image upload because `<input type="file" name="file[]">`

Comment: $extension=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]))); Please try this instead of that.

Comment: i get error in this line `$extension=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['files']['name'][$key])));` and this is the ERROR `Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`

Comment: only two images are stored in server and i get the above error

Comment: stop create multible accounts and start every time the same question. i think the best solution for you is to learn php. stop spam and rtmf

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't want to change the code, can you just make some change and work as i want **if i need a entire code i would just as question as** "i need to upload image and rename"**i just want to know whats wrong with my code